# customize Django CMS Navigation

Tags: django, django-cms

Now I want to create a website by Django CMS,but I am the first time to use Django CMS,and I don not have any Django knowlege(I am learning).
I want to customize the Navigation bar like the picture,what should I do,install a plugins or write the code by myself.
Please tell me.Thank you very much.

[image: like this picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically develop this yourself using Django CMS's navigation menu functionality:

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/how_to/menus.html

The above should give you enough to get started. Also, if you are just starting out I would recommend using hosted platform to kick things off (for example [Divio](https://www.divio.com/en/)).